# Python 3 not completing mysql delete query

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working on a legacy script upgrade to Python 3 however the script is hanging during a database delete command (DELETE FROM). The script is showing no error and the logger contains only the is_connected result which is true. Here's my test script based on the main.py file but with only the call to delete the contents of a table and reset it's auto increment prior to repopulating the table.

Here's my test.py file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import hashlib
from pprint import pprint
import mysql.connector
import configparser
import re
import random
import requests
import sys
import logging

# Load config for database variables
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

logFile = "logger.log"

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename=logFile,level=logging.DEBUG)

# Connect to the MySQL database
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=config["MySQL"]["host"],
    user=config["MySQL"]["user"],
    port=config["MySQL"]["port"],
    passwd=config["MySQL"]["password"],
    database=config["MySQL"]["database"]
)
cur = cnx.cursor()
logging.debug(cnx.is_connected())

# Clear the database ready to re-import
# Clear lookup tables first
cur.execute("DELETE FROM member_additional_skills")
logging.debug("Delete Done")
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_additional_skills AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
cnx.commit()
logging.debug("Finished!")
print("Done")
```

I've left this running for 20 minutes and still nothing else is logged after it declares Teue to being connectedand the process is still running. Is there anything I've missed here?

*** EDIT ***
The process is still in htop but is not using cpu so seems crashed right? And as i write this I have the following as the output to my python3 test.py command line:
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe and the process is no longer in htop

I should point out that this table has no more than 30 rows in it so would expect it to complete in milliseconds

thanks

Comment: Try adding commit after first `cur.execute`. While one `commit` usually works for multiple `execute` commands, possibly the `logging.debug()` interrupts the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TrUNCAtE member_additional_skills](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) OR `DROP member_additional_skills`  and `CREATE member_additional_skills(....)`

that is much faster

Comment: I replaced the first query as ```cur.execute("TRUNCATE member_additional_skills")``` but still the same result and I don't get past this step and no errors

Comment: run an CHECK table and a repair if necessary from mysql client

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a lock issue:
Sometime with the MySQL connector, the table lock's aren't released properly. Making the table unchangeable.

Try resetting the database and trying again!